# Parsing dynamic multiple form fields to float

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to parse the input fields with a specific class. However, only the value of the first field gets parsed and copied to the other fields

[image]

```
<?php foreach($income as $inc): ?>
 <input type="text" id="test" class="test" name="income[<?=$inc['id']?>]"/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My javascript is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.test').focusout(function(e) {
          var value = $('.test').val();
          if(value) {
            value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
            $('.test').val(value);
          }              
      });      
  });
```

Please note that the fields are dynamic, that's why I'm unable to use specific IDs. If I do so, I may have to reloop the javascript code.

Comment: [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) _Get the current value of the **first element** in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element._ that's why it's only parsing the first input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you need to use the current value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // collects all elements with the class test
  $('.test').focusout(function(e) {
          // foreach element in this collection do the following
          // get the current value
          var value = $(this).val();
          if(value) {
            value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
            // update if required
            $(this).val(value);
          }              
      });      
  });
```

Comment: Jesus christ. I thought Imma do some crazy voodoo. Thanks!